# Can there be more than one answer for matrix chain multiplication?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming, matrix-multiplication

I'm studying for an Algorithms exam, and one of my problems is to find the optimal matrix chain multiplication for the following:

A1: 5x7

A2: 7x10

A3: 10x7

A4: 7x5

I ended up with the solution ((A1*A2)A3)A4), which sums to 875 operations. The correct answer is marked as (A1(A2(A3*A4)), which also sums to 875. Are both answers correct, or is there some other thing here that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple optimal answers as can be seen from your example. You can also consider the trivial case with a set of matrices that all have the same dimensions (every sequence has the same cost).

You may want to note that the sequence of dimensions in your example is palindromic, so are the two possible optimal solutions.

There are no other criteria you can use without looking at the values of the matrices to optimize this further. Using the values of the matrices, one may think of improvements that can be done to minimize the time to get the final results (for example, use the order that gets to the 0 matrix fastest).